# LinQ GroupBy on nested element with same attributes

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following xml output:

```
<R N="1">
  <MT N="Section" V="Section-1" />
  <MT N="Person" V="John" />
</R>
<R N="2">
  <MT N="Section" V="Section-1" />
  <MT N="Person" V="Peter" />
</R>
<R N="3">
  <MT N="Section" V="Section-2" />
  <MT N="Person" V="Joseph" />
</R>
```

...
...

```
<R N="N">
  <MT N="Section" V="Section-J" />
  <MT N="Person" V="PersonX" />
</R>
```

Im trying to compose a LinQ query to group all results  by section, using the section value as Key and the entire element  as element selector:

```
//MyElements its an IEnumerable<XElement>
var something = MyElements.GroupBy
(
   x => x.Elements("MT")
   .Where
   (
     type => type.Attribute("N").Value == "Section"
   )
   .Select
   (
     type => type.Attribute("V").Value
   )
   ,
   x=>x
);
```

When i debug my something variable doesn't contain elements.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key selection ends up with an `IEnumerable<string>` as the result, which is definitely wrong. It should leave you with a plain `string`, achievable with

```
x => x.Elements("MT").Single(t => t.Attribute("N").Value == "Section")
                     .Attribute("V").Value
```

You also don't need the identity projection `x => x`, as it is implied.

Finally, the code given would never result in `something` being an empty enumerable if `MyElements` is itself non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly, it will be:

```
var res = doc.Descendants("MT")
             .Where(x => x.Attribute("N").Value == "Section")
             .GroupBy(x => x.Attribute("V").Value,
                      (k, v) => new { Key = k, List = v.Select(x => x.Parent).ToList() })
             .ToList();
```

with result:

[image]

Comment: Its exactly what's on the first response Konrad. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after is more like:

```
 var something = MyElements.GroupBy
        (
           x => x.Elements("MT")
           .First
           (
             type => type.Attribute("N").Value == "Section"
           )
           .Attribute("V").Value
           ,
           x=>x
        );
```

(albeit that last `x=>x` is not needed - its implied.)

Live example: http://rextester.com/MDAO1198